# Is there ValueInputOption parameter support in google sheet component in Apache camel?

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

The google sheet API (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption) mentions ValueInputOption as mandatory.
I am trying to write to googlesheet using google sheet component of Apache camel.

I am getting `ResolveEndpointFailedException`:

> org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve
>   endpoint:
>   google-sheets://data/update?ValueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&accessToken=....&applicationName=CamelGoogleApp&clientId=...&clientSecret=....&refreshToken=.....&spreadsheetId=....&values=#vrobj
>   due to: There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint.
>   Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are
>   properties of the endpoint. Unknown
>   parameters=[{ValueInputOption=USER_ENTERED}]

where camel version is `3.0.0-M3` and jars in use are `camel-spring-boot-starter` and `camel-google-sheets-starter`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use header `CamelGoogleSheets.valueInputOption` to pass `ValueInputOption` into producer.

```
from("direct:writeToSheet")
    .setHeader("CamelGoogleSheets.valueInputOption", constant("USER_ENTERED"))
    .to("google-sheets://xxx")
```

Comment: You might want to reference the [official documentation](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/components/modules/ROOT/pages/google-sheets-component.adoc) especially the paragraph that explains that options can either be specified via the URI or as `CamelGoogleSheets.<option>` header

Comment: @RomanVottner I have not included this quote intentionally. The docs states, that every option can be set either with URI param or header. For this concrete parameter I am not quite sure, if it can be specified as URI param (I have not found any field named `valueInputOption` and annotated with `@UriParam` in package `org.apache.camel.component.google.sheets`). Right now I am testing the URI alternative and will eventually edit answer, if this can be passed as URI param.